# How do I locate command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I locate command blocks? I was messing around with some commands and died, and lost the location where I was testing out a lot of stuff.  I do not have access to MCEdit or anything like that.  I accidentally took a screenshot, but didn't have co-ords up, if that helps.

Comment: *Sorry, but it's simply not possible.* | You can't *just* teleport to a random block of a specific type in Vanilla... Not even detect and print out the location of them. *Although I'd like to be able to do that with Diamond Ore...*

Comment: Well, it's possible, but it'll take forever. Try `/testforblock` on every single possible block that's not Sandstone; so for a Redstone flat world, Y is more than 56 (or 64; forgot the max height)

Comment: It's not a superflat world :/. But how would you testforblock within a radis?

Comment: Then that's going to get worse. Because you'll have to scan every single block, which will take forever. Alternatively, use a map editing program.

Comment: Like @aytimothy said, Try using a map editing program. I know you said you don't have access to MCEdit, but try downloading it, and select a large area within the map, and use the analyze function. This will return every block within the area you selected and how many of them there are.

Comment: Ok I will try and get MCEdit or something like that, thanks for the help.

Comment: Just an add-on to Dorian Dore's answer... You'll want to watch out which version you get; 2.0.0 (is I think a continuation of the beta builds, which has partial support 1.8+)

Comment: If it's not on a remote server, MCEdit will work out fine.  Any number of mapper programs could help as well.  The only real requirement for these programs is that you have local access to the map.

Comment: Yes, it's a singleplayer map, but I think I'm going to start over and just retype all the command blocks. Who knows, maybe I'll improve on them.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you remember any semi-unique part of your command<sup>1</sup>, you can use [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac).

Command Blocks are [Tile/Block Entities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tile_Entity), since a regular data value is not enough to store all information about them. Instead, they have NBT data similar to entities, which are detailed on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format). In particular, command blocks ("Control") have a `Command` entry. NBTExplorer is able to read the region format and search for a Tile Entity with a specific entry.

1. Open up the program and select *File > Open Minecraft Save Folder*<sup>2</sup>. You will get a list of folders corresponding to your worlds. Open up the world you want to search, and select the "Region" folder.
2. Go to *Search > Find* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). In the popup, under *Name*, enter "Command", and set *Value* to your code snippet. For example, I remember testing something on Pigs a while back, and I know that I used `type=Pig` in one or more commands in that contraption.

[image]

3. Click on *Find* and wait. If you remember your command snippet correctly, the program will find the corresponding Tile Entity. First of all, it shows you the exact command used. If that is not what you want, go to *Search > Find Next* (<kbd>F3</kbd>) and repeat this step. It also shows you the xyz coordinates of the block, which you can use to teleport yourself to the command block in game.

[image]

This method can be used to locate all Tile Entities and regular Entities in a savegame, as long as you have sufficiently unique NBT data for it. For example, you can use it to locate that Chest that you put your "Gunblade" in (`Items`, `name:Gunblade`), or figure out where your horse of yours has wandered off to (`OwnerUUID`, `[your UUID]` or `Tame`, `1`).

<sup>1 Meaning there shouldn't be too many command blocks including that snippet.</sup>

<sup>2 If you have set a different Game Directory for your Minecraft profile, select *Open Folder" and navigate to your saves manually.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

---

Your screenshot won't help if there is no co-ordinates on it.

---

You can use a map renderer to (hopefully) find your command block though, like [Minecraft Overviewer](http://overviewer.org/) or [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You could download X-Rays or something and turn them on...
But make sure your render distance is on a very far amount.