# Dying Repeatedly on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I go to a certain location of my server in creative mode, I instantly die and spawn at my spawn point and then die again repeatedly for 8 more times. Then afterwards when I fly back to where I died I die again repeatedly. I don't die anywhere else except at that location.

I believe this happened because someone set down the command block that keeps killing me. I need help.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Comment: Also, try Googling your question, rather than just ranting into Stack Exchange. You'll probably get more help that way.

Comment: Note: the teleportation loop question pertains to any rouge command block.  Considering what happened, the simplest answer would be someone had command block permissions or there was no restrictions on command blocks.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution as it is your server and you have access to console.  Turn on console logging with [gamerule command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#gamerule):

```
/gamerule logAdminCommands true
```

This will allow you to look in console the next time you die as any command block being used to kill you will output something similar to this:

> CommandBlock at 7,51,1 issued server command: kill @a

This will give you the coordinates to the rogue command block.  Then using the [setblock command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setblock) you can set those coordinates to air.  In my example, this would be command:

```
/setblock 7 51 1 air
```

Or if you want to leave the command block but stop it from killing you, you can change the block to require redstone with the [blockdata command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#blockdata):

```
/blockdata 7 51 1 {auto:0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for a command block that's set on a timer to kill `@p`, the closest player.  Using NBTExplorer against a backup of your map, you should be able to locate the location of this problematic resource.

Similar question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230213/199492