# I need to teleport someone with specific death count scoreboard. 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My friends and I are playing a Hardcore style playthrough of Minecraft. We want instead of death being permanent, teleport the player to a challenge area that gets harder the more you die. The commands I've tried already haven't seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Minecraft commands have no `event` system, you cannot just say: 'run when someone dies'. Instead, you need to keep track of a *separate* `deathCount` variable that constantly get set back to zero. The purpose of this is to detect when a player dies. If they die, their score goes up by one, your commands run, then it goes back to zero. If they don't die, nothing happens. Therefore, you use this temporary variable to detect when they die, because if they are to die, their score goes up by one for *one, and only one* iteration of a command block chain.

To summarize, you keep track of two `deathCount` variables. One is the normal one, to tell you how *many* times they have died in total, so you know which platform to teleport them to. The other is a `Temp` variable, which serves only to tell you *when* they die, so you are not constantly teleporting them to a specific spot, but only when and if they die.

## Setup

```
scoreboard objectives add totalDeaths deathCount {"text":"Number of Times Died"}
scoreboard objectives add tempDeaths deathCount
```

## An example loop

```
execute as @e[scores={totalDeaths=..0,tempDeaths=1}] in minecraft:the_overworld run tp @s 0 64 0   #If they die without dying, they spawn at spawn
execute as @e[scores={totalDeaths=1,tempDeaths=1}] in minecraft:the_nether run tp @s 64 64 64      #Where I assume your first platform are. You can also add datapack dimensions here
execute as @e[scores={totalDeaths=2,tempDeaths=1}] in minecraft:the_nether run tp @s 64 64 -64     #The second platform? All of these are subject to change, this is an example
...                                          # However many more platforms you want

scoreboard players set @a tempDeaths 0       # So that once they die, they do not then constantly get teleported back to that one spot on the platform. If you mess up and create a teleporting loop, there are lots of great answers on Arqade to get you out of it
```

Comment: should i put these in command blocks

Comment: I used a datapack function file as an example, but you can easily use command blocks, with one per line. Keep in mind that these need to be in a command block chain, and that you need to remove my comments

Comment: I apologies all the commands work except that its clears the temp death to fast in a chain block. so they do not get teleported. If I take away the clear tempdeaths command  then they get stuck in a teleport loop. How should I fix this

Comment: Either put back the tempDeaths, or you will need to look at this answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230213/265096

Comment: I can gladly put back the temp deaths. but i if add it to the the chain it goes to fast so that it clears the temp death before they are teleported

Comment: You want to add it to the *end* of the chain, so it happens *after* everything else has a chance to happen

Comment: I did and it ticks so fast that it all happens at once but I figured if I put a range of number to check for and then a condition to the set a Redstone block with repeaters for a timer it works perfectly. thank you for your help!