# Minecraft command block(s) run amok

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

My Minecraft server gives me two of these messages a second (probably from a friend's mischief)...

```
[15:23:51 INFO]: [@: The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format]
```

I disable command blocks in server.properties and it stops. But I'm pretty sure it will come back when I re-enable it. How do I ferret out the offending thing and stop/delete it (preferably from the server console)?  It's not telling me what/where it is.  Do I have to nuke and pave the entire world?

Or is it harmless except for the message? Should I just disable the output and let it go?

Comment: Right now it's harmless, but there is a slim possibility that it isn't so harmless if it ever manages to succeed.

(I'd be more concerned with the redstone clock that is running at 0.5Hz.)