# How to remove infinite potion effects?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I accidently stepped on a block which triggered infinite slowness 5 and I cant get rid of it. Milk doesn't work,

```
/effect @p 2 0 or /effect @p clear
```

doesn't work either.

How can I get rid of this? I tried shutting down Minecraft but it was still no good. It's really bugging me since I'm trying to create an adventure map. Any help? Also if you can help but need to know how this happened, here's the command:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:wool 15 effect @a slowness 1000000 5
```

[Edit] I've found that if I keep activating a command block with the command:

> /effect player(BruhTemmieLlama2) 2 0

The potion effect would disappear for a second.

[Edit2] I found a temporary solution.  If I spammed a lever attached to a command block with the command a few lines up, the effect would go away.
So I turned the command block purple by turning on options "Repeat" and 
"Always Active" and the effect would disappear. But if i removed the command from the command block, the effect would come back.
I'd still like to know a way to permantly be rid of these effects. Thx pals!

Comment: Milk and both of those commands you tried should work. Make sure that there's not a command applying slowness to you again.

Comment: Is the command block with the /execute command still running?

Comment: So you are successfully removing the effect, and then its getting reapplied again. Sounds like the block giving you the effect is on repeat as well, and constantly giving you slowness 5 again and again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've lost a command block, how can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161304/ive-lost-a-command-block-how-can-i-find-it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that your problem is that the command block is still running (stated in the comments above).  One possible solution to this is to download and use MCEdit from [here](http://www.mcedit.net/downloads.html), along with the filter called Dump Command Blocks ([here](http://elemanser.com/DumpCommandBlocks.py) for download, [here](http://elemanser.com/filters.html) for information) to find all command blocks in a selection (either use Select All if that's a thing or just select a very large area near your character).  I'm not totally sure if MCEdit has a method to do this built-in, but if it doesn't, just use that filter.

Find and delete the command block that is doing the potion effect.  The DumpCommandBlocks filter, I believe, dumps the coordinates of command blocks to a text file.  Maybe go over that list of coordinates either in regular Minecraft or in MCEdit to find and delete it.

Good luck!