# S.O.S Minecraft Spam. How do I stop it? (Commands)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Ok so I got on my friend's server the other day and there was text spamming all over the screen. It's still going on! I've tried using.

```
/gamerule commandblockoutput false
```

However, it doesn't work. I've also tried to look for the command block. Can anyone help me with ways to get rid of the command block?

[image: insert image description]

Comment: Try going into the console to see what command is executing.

Answer (score 0):

## Destroy it.

Unfortunately, there is no way to suppress all print outputs.

The `/gamerule commandblockoutput false` command only suppresses admin/debug/info messages; the annoying ones that show up when you for example `/tp`, `/clone` or `/give`.

You can suppress them in the console by using `/gamerule logAdminCommands false`. As for stopping the printing, **the only way to stop it is to find the command block with the `/tellraw`, `/say` or `/msg` command is to destroy it**.

As for finding the command block, [you can use the method outlined in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161304/ive-lost-a-command-block-how-can-i-find-it), assuming you can remember part of the command (or derive a part of it from the output) to locate the command block and then `/setblock [x] [y] [z] air 0 replace`.