# How can I find a specific block (preferably in a large area) in my minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have lost a very valuable shulker block in an ocean, in my minecraft world. It had 56 diamonds, 64 iron bars, few gold ores, a trident, a nautilus shell, a heart of the sea, and a few stacks of ice. It is very valuable, and I really want it back, but I don't know where I left it. The sea is way too large to explore it by myself, so are there any ways to get it?
*P.S. My world is in 1.16, so mcedit doesn't work. It also has cheats and commands disabled, but I can make a copy of my world and work on that one.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've lost a command block, how can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161304/ive-lost-a-command-block-how-can-i-find-it)

Comment: Another way to allow cheats to work, rather than making a copy, is to open your world up to LAN and enable cheats when you do so.

Comment: If you're playing minecraft Vanilla without cheats, it's practically impossible. If you install any texture or Mod ...

Comment: You can download a hacked client such as wurst. These clients often times have built in functions that help you find specific blocks. If you do use this method I advise that you set very strict boundaries what you can and cannot use such a client for since not doing so can easily ruin the fun of the game as you might start using x-ray for everything.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that brb in a few minutes

Comment: ok I didn't figure it out I'm gonna try that again tommorow