# How can I locate a misplaced shulkerbox?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a typical problem, most players went through before I guess. I placed my shulkerbox somewhere, but cannot remember where I did. Either that, or it isn't where I thought it was.

Is there a way to locate a specific shulkerbox in the world? The box is renamed. I have access to a world save.

I found answers in the web to try and use MCEdit to open the world and filter for the block, however, MCEdit has not been updated for three years and fails to open my 1.17 world.

Comment: Related: [I've lost a command block, how can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/161304/185203)

Answer (score 3):

Try copying the world and going on creative and searching for it. If you find it, then note down the coordinates and go into your real world and find it there.