# How can I turn off a repeating command block if I don't know its coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've placed a command block and it is spawning mobs. I don't know its coordinates and without that I can't turn it off. That world is a huge build and if I can't break the command block I will lose the world! Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: Sounds like https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do ?

Comment: As Timmy Jim suggests: does this answer your question? [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)

Comment: Second duplicate target:  [I've lost a command block, how can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161304/ive-lost-a-command-block-how-can-i-find-it)