# Minecraft Daylight cycle issue

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have downloaded a world (a mansion build) online into my Minecraft game. The world I download does not have a daylight cycle. It remains daytime all the time. I have tried to turn this off by doing both gamerule dodaylightcycle false and gamerule dodaylightcycle true. Both haven't worked and it always remains daytime. Is there any way other I can fix this?

Comment: What happens when you try `/time set night`? Does it instantly go back to day?

Comment: yes it does, always goes back to day

Comment: Which means there is a command somewhere doing `/time set day`. Your best bet would be [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161304/ive-lost-a-command-block-how-can-i-find-it) question. Locate the command block and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

By using `/gamerule dodaylightcycle true` you need to wait some time. You can also change time using `/time set 1000` for day and `/time set 18000` for night. If none of this work, I really have no idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`\daylock false`

It is a shortcut command to the `dodaylightcycle`.

Comment: How do you go to the settings of the world? And what should you change there?

Answer (score 0):

The creator of the map most likely made a command block set to repeat to keep it always daytime as part of the map. Disabling command blocks should do the trick if this is it.