# How to find lost command block using mac compatible tools without NBTExplorer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to find a command block in my world but I don't know where it is, and I can't use NBTExplorer because that's incompatible with my computer.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Why incompatible? It runs natively on Windows, with Wine on Linux and probably Mac and I don't know any other system that runs Minecraft. (But it's still a good question in case there's ever a change to Minecraft's save format that NBTExplorer doesn't support.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've lost a command block, how can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161304/ive-lost-a-command-block-how-can-i-find-it)

Comment: Personally, I consider these "arbitrarily exclude the existing answer" questions to be not very useful, but that aside there are already several answers to the canonical that don't mention NBTExplorer.

Comment: The thing is NBTExplorer doesn't work with macOS 10.15.7 as in: it is 32 bit but I can't run 32 bit apps.

Comment: But then I'm afraid it's either a question about a Mac (how to run 32-bit software) or a software ID question (where can I find..), and both are off-topic here.